# Abstractions, solid and property injection vs constructor injection

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have a discussion with someone at my work. The classes and interfaces look like the following:

```
public interface ISomeInterface { }

public class ImplementationOfInterface : ISomeInterface { }

public class ClassThatUsesInterface {
    private ISomeInterface _interface;

    public ISomeInterface Interface {
         get => _interface ?? new ImplementationOfInterface();
         set => _interface = value;
    }
}
```

99% of the time we would use `ImplementationOfInterface`. The last 1% would probably be unit testing purposes.

I have tried reading up on Dependency Injection, Dependency Inversion Principle, Service, SOLID and a bit more unrelated things like Service Locator pattern/anti-pattern, two step initialization anti-pattern and so on, but have not found anyone describing this way of doing it.

It's half-way clear that the D in SOLID is violated; "Dependency inversion principle;
one should "depend upon abstractions, [not] concretions.". Since it's fairly easy to override this in unit tests or switch the implementation if you'd like to... which makes me even more confused about it..

Even tho it might be against the D in SOLID and does not really do anything following proper dependency injection, it's really hard to argue against this usage.

Personally I have suggested to inject the instance through the constructor, but my colleagues thinks this is too much extra work, and don't see the benefits. To be honest, I'm having a hard time not agreeing, but I still have a bad feeling about it..

Can you come up with articles or powerful arguments for and against the use of this particular "hack"?

Comment: Note htat the S in SOLID is also stepped upon, especially when ImplementationOfInterface is IDisposable or has construction parameters. It is not the task of ClassThatUsesInterface to manage the  lifecycle or dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that `ClassThatUsesInterface` even needs to *know* that `ImplementationOfInterface` exists is a code smell. You might need to add a `using` directive for some totally unrelated namespace for this to compile, perhaps even a reference to some other project or package or `dll`. And so, your code begins to tangle and your dependencies start to cause headaches.

I realise this is a trimmed-down demo  example, but `ImplementationOfInterface` just *happens* to take no dependencies itself. What if it did? Would you `new` those up in turn? And *their* dependencies..? This then shows that you're violating another SOLID principle here - you will need to modify this class every time you change the `ctor` args to `ImplementationOfInterface`. That violates the open/Closed principle.

Comment: Love this one... It's 100% true, a very trimmed down version, and yes, all the following classes follow the same pattern. They all new up their dependencies in public properties...

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor to inject the dependency. You don't want to allow changing the implementation halfway during the lifetime of an instance of `ClassThatUsesInterface`

Note that some DI frameworks or implementations do not support property injection. Like Asp.Net Core for example.

Also, using the property like you do now you have to have intimite knowlegde of the default implementation of the property (which should not be known to the class, you are now coupling it) is not set as it is hidden. Whereas if you explicitly use the constructor it is clear for all.

Comment: Very good argument. But I'm afraid it won't change my colleagues minds... I'll need more... The lifetime of our objects are very short, as they often live per web request.. Altho possible, I'm afraid this argument alone is going to carry to little weight :(

Comment: Why do you think the lifetime is relevant?  Almost all APS.NET objects have Request scope.

Comment: @bommelding not sure if he is using asp.net at all

Comment: @bommelding: It should not be relevant indeed, but that is likely the arguments my colleagues will come with.

Comment: @PeterBons We use a mix of web pages (of various types, razor.net asp.net++), nservicebuses, command line tools, windows services and msmq messages... quite the load...

Comment: @PeterBons - "live per web request" was clear enough.